# Define TypeScript Type of object whose keys which are not in an array match the type of a second object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a utility function, `copyKnownProperties` to copy properties from one class / object to another only if the key exists on both objects. In my example, you can see I am attempting to copy properties on `B` to `A`. The JavaScript portion of this works fine.

I would like for TypeScript to warn me when I'm trying to copy properties that have a mismatched type. In my example, you can see that both `A` and `B` have the same keys. But only the `foo` has the same `string` type between the two. This part I also have working.

The problem is that I would like to avoid this error by including the key in an `omit` array. These values will be omitted from the copying process, and therefore I do not need to be warned about their mismatched types. But I'm not sure how to tell TypeScript this.

*tl;dr - I want the error on line 27 to go away because of the properties I'm passing in the `omit` array.*

[[TypeScript Playground Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgFA9gBwK4BsCGAXApgZ2mQCcVdjsBLA6RAO2gANtFHoB3S7ACyNOXJUaiAGbQeuaPkwBbSQGtcAT2gjSMpmsQzGUWMCgjUdAMZV60EyiUBpOonZ14-QdXwAeACrRcADzx0ACaE8JgUlJjo7gBiAHwANNDRPv64QYSIAEYAVrhmsQAUeuKIAFzQnvHFWjLl0VUwtDJc5QWKSqJJ0AA+0O2dngCUANoAutAAvNBjUIPl3gDexQUA8jl52AB07fgFLIPQmIRtygMjo4ObIojEAKKYJtwFJ0oHE7HQS43Q0JRiL78GDVoAAyEHQACE2i4m0opnQqECBBegwOLGG7XGUxqGOUowA3MUAL6DQmNYi4bCoYgMFhkolQKBWOj4bDQACC5S+P2uZSk2GIcIA5mSfpkwuU6KgZJlyKLoOKAF7lTKIRDoXCYOj0yafapq8oAcl5hoaYol0AAjGaFZhleJiKhcFAGZAmfRWdAAEJc-V81mCugi4ri4jlAPC+VK8MCyMu3Xc1QG6CGiNB00hi2p2Ppm3RlNpoWGl2MyBWZC2eyOZxkcLI9mJL2JYYAIlDLcSbbtLYuZKAA)]

[image: typescript playground screenshot]

Comment: Note that in your example, in `A`, the `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, are not `static`, so they belong to the _instances_, not the class object itself.

Comment: You need to provide clarity about whether you want to deal with classes or objects. The function indicates objects, but the example indicates classes.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I didn't realize there was a meaningful difference between the two in this context. I would prefer it work for both, but would settle for starting with objects. I've updated my question, hopefully that makes things more clear.

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  Also for this to be a [mre] it really shouldn't have any problems you're not asking about; since all those class properties are in error, could you maybe either initialize them or come up with some other code that doesn't have the problem?  And I agree with previous commenters... your example code doesn't do anything at runtime, because the `A` and `B` *constructors* don't have those properties.

Comment: Omit all keys in the array from F and use that as your generic constraint for T: https://tsplay.dev/mpjZgw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified [vr.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/vr)'s answer and settled on this.

```
/**
 * Populates properties on `to` with properties of the same key from `from`
 */
export function copyKnownProperties<
  To extends Partial<Omit<From, Omitted[number]>>,
  From extends object,
  Omitted extends (keyof From)[] = [],
>(to: To, from: From, omit?: Omitted): To {
  (Object.keys(to) as (keyof To)[]).forEach((key) => {
    if (key in from && (!omit || !omit.includes(key as string as keyof From))) {
      to[key as keyof To] = from[
        key as string as keyof From
      ] as unknown as To[keyof To];
    }
  });
  return to;
}
```